# How can you model the arrival times of 2 different events?

Tags: poisson-distribution

I was looking at a poisson process and using an exponential distribution to model arrival times of the event.

For example the chances that a person is arriving at a bus stop. Then in the simple case I'd like to model the arrival of the bus and I'd use another exponential for that.

What I'm trying to think of is what if there is something else that happens.

For example the person changes his mind and decides to walk.

In that case to put it simply:

- person arrives
- one of the following happens whichever is first

  - bus arrives
  - person gets bored and decides to walk

I can imagine cases where the above is independent and also where it's not - ie if the person has been waiting for 1hr it's more likely they have gotten bored.

How would you approach this?

One way I've thought is simulating each "minute" what happens. Ie some prob that a bus arrives and then some prob that they get bored and create a state transtiiton type setup.